# Understanding Service Worker scope

Tags: javascript, scope, service-worker

I am trying to implement a `Service Worker` in a test page. My end goal is an application that operates offline. The folder structure is below

```
/myApp
  ...
  /static
    /mod
      /practice
        service-worker.js
        worker-directives.js
        foopage.js
  /templates
    /practice
      foopage.html
```

I am registering a service worker as shown below (within `service-worker.js`):

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('../static/mod/practice/service-worker.js').then(function(reg) {
    console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
    ...
}
```

and in the console I see

`Registration succeeded. Scope is https://example.com/static/mod/practice/`

If my page is located at `https://example.com/practice/foopage`, do I need to make sure that my `service worker` scope is `https://example.com/practice/foopage`?

If I try to define the scope in the `register` function call like

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('../static/mod/practice/service-worker.js', { scope: '/practice/foopage/' }).then(function(reg) {
    ...
}
```

I get the error

```
Registration failed with SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The path of the provided scope ('/practice/foopage/') is not under the max scope allowed ('/static/mod/practice/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker script, or use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the scope.
```

**Question is:** What exactly does *scope* refer to? Is it the collection of URLs that the `service worker` will eventually control? Do I need to move `service-workers.js` somewhere else? If so, where?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75532652/angular-service-worker-scope-encountered-an-error-during-installation. I get to configure it for angular `v15.2.0`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Service workers are basically a proxy between your web application and the internet, so it can intercept calls to the network if so desired.

Scope in this instance refers to the path that the service worker will be able to intercept network calls from. The `scope` property can be used explicitly define the scope it will cover. However:

Service workers can only intercept requests originating in the scope of the current directory that the service worker script is located in and its subdirectories. [Or as MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Why_is_my_service_worker_failing_to_register):

> The service worker will only catch requests from clients under the service worker's scope.
>
> The max scope for a service worker is the location of the worker.

As your service worker is located in `/static/mod/practice/`, it's not allowed to set its scope to `/practice/foopage/`. Requests to other hosts, e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/foo`, can be intercepted in any case.

The easiest way to ensure that your service worker can intercept all the calls it needs to, would be to place it in the root directory of your web app (`/`). You can also override the default restrictions using an http header and manually setting the scope (see Ashraf Sabry's answer).

Comment: I didn't think a `js` file in the root directory was ever something that would be done. But with new concepts come new paradigms I guess

Comment: I think it is mainly for security reasons. If you only have access to `/static`, but not to the root (`/`) for example, your service worker shouldn't be able to intercept requests to the root.

Comment: This is only partly correct—the scope determines which pages are controlled by the service worker. Once a page is controlled by a service worker, *all* HTTP requests originating from the page, regardless of the request URL, will trigger the service worker's `fetch` event. So if a controlled page makes an AJAX request for `https://thirdpartyapi.com/api/test`, your service worker will have a chance to intercept that.

Comment: `the scope determines which pages are controlled by the service worker` - this REALLY tripped me up, so thanks for the tip @JeffPosnick

Answer (score 62):

Leave the service worker file in whatever directory imposed by your project structure and set the `scope` option to `/` and add the `Service-Worker-Allowed` HTTP header to the response of your service worker file.

I'm using IIS, so I would add the following to web.config file:

```
<location path="static/mod/practice/service-worker.js">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Service-Worker-Allowed" value="/" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

And register the worker by:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/static/mod/practice/service-worker.js', { scope: '/' })
        .then(function (registration)
        {
          console.log('Service worker registered successfully');
        }).catch(function (e)
        {
          console.error('Error during service worker registration:', e);
        });
```

Tested on Firefox and Chrome.

Refer to the examples in [Service worker specification](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-script-response)

Comment: I was setted http response to Service-Worker-Allowed : / but still it does not works for me. It register SW and just after 1 sec unregister that service worker automatically. Can you please check at https://demo3.icubes.org

Answer (score 14):

For the people who are using nginx it couldn't be any simpler:

```
# Given that /static is your route to assets
location /static {
        # using / as root scope
        add_header Service-Worker-Allowed /;
....
```

Comment: My service worker was not registering. I thought the issue was with the scope. I gave your solution a try and now the service worker registers successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case if the scope changes between development & production environment, as often we use local subdirectories for projects, using "./" for the scope may save the day (& make it dynamic).

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(
    `./service-worker.js`, 
    {
        scope: `./`
    }
);
```

Comment: Adding the scope to my service worker this way did the trick.