# How to automatically attach header in all http requests from client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, http-headers

Im looking for a way in javascript, to automatically attach a header to any http requests the page makes wheather its static file assets or api calls, etc... I read in some other posts like these, that using a service worker could help, but I couldn't get it working for me. Also the server I make requests to, allows CORS to the server I'm making requests from.

[serviceworker is it possible to add headers to url request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503836/serviceworker-is-it-possible-to-add-headers-to-url-request)

[How to intercept all http requests including form submits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813770/how-to-intercept-all-http-requests-including-form-submits)

[Adding custom headers in Javascript for all http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029978/adding-custom-headers-in-javascript-for-all-http-requests)

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#6E2D91">
    <meta name="description" content="Sample Web App">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { 
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {   
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceworker.js').then(
            function(registration) { 
              // Registration was successful
              console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope); }, 
            function(err) { 
              // registration failed :( 
              console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err); 
            }); 
        });
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        fetch("https://data.global");
      }, 5000);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my service worker

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(customHeaderRequestFetch(event))
});

function customHeaderRequestFetch(event) {
    // decide for yourself which values you provide to mode and credentials

    // Copy existing headers
    const headers = new Headers(event.request.headers);

    // Set a new header
    headers.set('x-my-custom-header', 'The Most Amazing Header Ever');
    // Delete a header
    headers.delete('x-request');

    const newRequest = new Request(event.request, {
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'omit',
        headers: headers
    })
    return fetch(newRequest)
}
```

You can see I am making a fetch call 5 seconds later. I expect it to get my custom header when sending out. If I were to inject into the DOM a  tag and set a source, or embed a huge html string with script tags, link tags, etc... I would expect all the http requests to get their static content to have the header on it. But currently it does not attach the header.

How can I get this to work?