# Using 'Service-Worker-Allowed' in Asp.net Web.Config (Unwanted Url at top of PWA)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have the following website hosting two PWAs.

```
www.xy.com/z
```

I have *PWA A* hosted on

```
www.xy.com/z/a
```

and *PWA B* hosted on

```
www.xy.com/z/b
```

I register a service worker for *PWA A* from the origin `www.xy.com/z/a` like this.

```
           if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('/z/a/sw.js', {scope: '/'}).then(function (registration) {
                     console.log('Service worker registration succeeded:', registration);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error);
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Service workers are not supported.');
            }
```

I register a service worker for *PWA B* from the origin `www.xy.com/z/b` the same way

```
             if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
                    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/z/b/sw.js', {scope: '/'}).then(function (registration) {
                         console.log('Service worker registration succeeded:', registration);
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('Service workers are not supported.');
                }
```

As far as registering the service workers and redirecting to the propert start_urls, everything seems to be fine. Both PWAs are prompted for A2HS automatically and installed to the app section of the device. The problem is both *PWA A* and *B* access shared content on `www.xy.com/z/`. When their service workers serve out of scope content from `www.xy.com/z/` **I get an unwanted browser URL displaying at the top of the PWA.**

I expected to be able to fix this by adding [Service-Worker-Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068714) to my web.config to indicate that these service workers could serve content outside of their scope.

```
 <location path="z/a/sw.js">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Service-Worker-Allowed" value="/" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>

<location path="z/b/sw.js">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Service-Worker-Allowed" value="/" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Should I be able to eliminate the browser url showing when redirecting to out of scope content (of the same domain) using `Service-Worker-Allowed` or have I misunderstood this?

**Edit:**

I have verified `Service-Worker-Allowed` is added to the header with chrome tools even though we knew it was because the out-of-scope service worker suddenly registered.

Android

- Samsung Internet (9.2.10.15) works as expected. Does not show url.
- Chrome (74.0.3729.157) browser url shows in PWA

IOS

- Safari (IOS 12.3.1) The url shows in PWA with a *'done'* button.
- Oddly in Safari if I comment out the service worker and add to home screen I get no url.