# How can I change the scope of a Service Worker in Blazor?

Tags: service-worker, blazor

I understand that in order to register a Service Worker in a directory other than "/" (wwwroot in Blazor Server) I need to:

1) Add the scope to the registration:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/static/mod/practice/service-worker.js', { scope: '/' })
    .then(function (registration)
    {
      console.log('Service worker registered successfully');
    }).catch(function (e)
    {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', e);
    });
```

(Source [Understanding Service Worker scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780397/understanding-service-worker-scope))

2) Add http header `Service-Worker-Allowed`
(Source [Understanding Service Worker scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780397/understanding-service-worker-scope) and https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-script-response)

Question: How can I add the `Service-Worker-Allowed` header in a Blazor Server project?