# Fetch of the service worker doesn't seem to get triggered

Tags: service-worker, service-worker-events

When a browser requests an image from the server, the call is getting picked up by an API controller in the back end. There, a authorization check must be done before returning the image in order to check if the request is allowed or not.

So I need to add the authorization header and when searching for the best solution, I found this article: https://www.twelve21.io/how-to-access-images-securely-with-oauth-2-0/ and I was mostly intereseted in the solution number 4 which uses a Service Worker.

I made my own implementation, I registered a serviceWorker:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log("serviceWorker active");
    window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
}
else {
    console.log("serviceWorker not active");
}

function onLoad() {
    console.log("onLoad is called");
    var scope = {
        scope: '/api/imagesgateway/'
    };
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/Scripts/ServiceWorker/imageInterceptor.js', scope)
        .then(registration => console.log("ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ", registration.scope))
        .catch(error => console.error("ServiceWorker registration failed: ", error));
}
```

and this is in my imageInterceptor:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log("fetch event triggered");
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request, {
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include',
            header: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'
            }
        })
    )
});
```

When I run my application, I see in my console that the registration seems to be successfully executed as I see the console.logs printed (ServiceWorker active, onLoad is called and successful registration with correct scope: https://localhost:44332/api/imagesgateway/

But when I load an image (https://localhost:44332/api/imagesgateway/...) via the gateway, I still get a 400 and when put a breakpoint on the backend I see that the authentication header is still null. Also, I don't see "fetch event triggered" message in my console. In another article it is stated that I can see the registered service workers via this setting: chrome://inspect/#service-workers but I don't see my worker there either.

My question is: Why isn't the authorization header added? Is it because, although the registration seems to go successfully, this isn't actually the case and therefore I don't see the worker in inspect#service-workers either?

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing `fetch event triggered` in the browser console because your Service Worker script isn't allowed to intercept the image requests. This is because your Service Worker script is located in a directory *outside* the scope of the requests you're interested in.

In order to intercept requests that handle resources at
`/api/imagesgateway/`
the SW script needs to be located in either
`/`, `/api/`, or `/api/imagesgateway/`. It cannot be located in `/some/other/directory/service-worker.js`.

This is the reason that your Service Worker registers successfully! There is no probelm in *registering* the SW. The problem lies in what it can do.

More info: [Understanding Service Worker scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780397/understanding-service-worker-scope)

Comment: I see now I forgot to mention that I try to implement the Service Worker in an ASP.NET MVC web application. I had to add a setting to the web.config (<add name="Service-Worker-Allowed" value="/" />) In the meanwhile I got the service worker working but now I am getting 2 request in my API for one image request. But I believe that is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue.
I've registered a Service Worker for right scope. But something goes wrong.
The main goal of my SW is intercepting browser's requests to static files of remote RestAPI.
These requests are generated by `<img>` and `<iframe>` elements of my html-page.

And something strange is observed: requests from `<iframe>` tags are handled properly, all works fine. But requests from `<img>` tags are not passed through Service Worker! For example if I put URL of requested image into `<iframe>` element the request is handled by SW. But! If I use `<img>` element with the same image`s URL - the request doesn't intercepted by Service Worker. Why?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).