# Embed service worker in application JS

Tags: javascript, function, service, service-worker

Now service worker is called with:

```
 navigator.serviceWorker.register('/js/sw.js')
        .then(function (swReg) {
```

Can I call it like that:

```
var sw = //paste here all sw.js file's code;
navigator.serviceWorker.register(//call sw variable)
            .then(function (swReg) {
```

I know that `serviceWorker.register` can contain only path to sw.js but can I embed sw.js in app.js in someway?

Comment: No. Because it runs on a scope different than the DOM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API explains it better.

Comment: @ITgoldman Thank you for reply. app.js will be used on different sites and it works only when domain has sw.js on its server. Can I include sw.js with url in app.js and then register service worker?

Comment: Probably not. Needs to be on same domain https://stackoverflow.com/a/72382370/3807365