# Angular service-worker scope encountered an error during installation

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker, service-worker-config

I am trying to use the Angular service worker but I get an error when trying to use it.

Those are my versions:

```
Angular CLI: 15.2.0
Node: 16.18.1
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: linux x64

Angular: 15.2.0
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, localize, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, service-worker

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.0
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.0
@schematics/angular             15.2.0
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

When I try to use the swPush in a function:

```
  subscribeToNotifications() {
    console.log('subscribeToNotifications: ');
    this.swPush.requestSubscription({
      serverPublicKey: VAPID.publicKey
    })
      .then(sub => {
        console.log('User accepts: ', sub);
        this.alertService.success('Your browser will show up our notifications', AlertOptions.options)
      })
      .catch(err => console.error("Could not subscribe to notifications", err));
  }
```

Then I get this error:

```
Service worker registration failed with: TypeError: ServiceWorker script at http://localhost:<port>/<out-path>/ngsw-worker.js for scope http://localhost:<port>/<out-path>/ encountered an error during installation.
```

I have follow the official guide posted [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/), but I can't get this to work.

The `ngsw.json` and the `ngsw-worker.js` are generated in the path set in the `angular.json` > `outputPath`. Let's called it **out-path**.

The files `angular.json` and `package.json` seem to be overwritten correctly, and my `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
...
        OverlayModule,
        ServiceWorkerModule.register('/<out-path>/ngsw-worker.js', {
          enabled: true, // should be environment.production
          // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
          // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
          registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
        })
...
```

All configuration files, seems to be fine, but I cannot get the service-worker register for some reason.

I am launching the app with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js`.
I would like to run this in Dev mode, but if someone knows how to get this work in production, it would be fine as well.

### Update

I have upgraded Angular from v13 to the latest v15.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use a `service worker` in `dev` mode. I encorage you (future readers) to take a look to this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780397/understanding-service-worker-scope) for understanding the concept of a service worker.

My files had been generated successfully, the problem was with the `scope`. You should  **NOT** use the `out-path` of the `angular.json` in the register method but the `--base-href` that you use when building the project. That href is the route from the `/` of your server to the path where you host your application on that server.

So if you build your project with:

```
ng build \
  --configuration <your-profile> \
  --base-href /<path-to-your-app>/
```

> Note: You should put "path-to-your-app" in between forward slashes.

Then, in the `app.module.ts` you should have something like this:

```
...
        OverlayModule,
        ServiceWorkerModule.register('/<path-to-your-application>/ngsw-worker.js', {
          enabled: true, // should be environment.production
          // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
          // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
          registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
        })
...
```